# How to pass to the outside scope (without console.log) a variable inside an .evaluate callback in google earth engine?

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

I have this callback inside the .evaluate function on google earth engine:

```
numberServer.evaluate(function(numberClient) {
  console.log('Client-side primitive data type', typeof numberClient);  // number
  console.log('Client-side number', numberClient);  // 10.3
  console.log('Client-side number used in expression', numberClient + 10);  // 20.3
})
```

The above will correctly output the value of numberServer to the client.

The problem is that I need to capture the value of numberClient in a variable. How can I do that?

I tried using a promise with no success.

```
function Test(){ return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    numberServer.evaluate(function(numberClient) {
        console.log('Client-side primitive data type', typeof numberClient);  // number
        console.log('Client-side number', numberClient);  // 10.3
        console.log('Client-side number used in expression', numberClient + 10);  // 20.3
  
        resolve(numberClient);
    })
});
};

var test2;

async function test3() {
    return test2 = await Test();
}

var test4;

(async function(){
  test4 = await test3();
})();


var test5 = test4;
```

test5 is always undefined and that's the variable I want to have.

I also tried returning the callback:

```
function Test() { return numberServer.evaluate(function(numberClient) {
  console.log('Client-side primitive data type', typeof numberClient);  // number
  console.log('Client-side number', numberClient);  // 10.3
  console.log('Client-side number used in expression', numberClient + 10);  // 20.3
  return numberClient;
})
};


var out = Test();
```

Comment: `var test4` creates `test4` as `undefined`. You then run an `async` IIFE which hits the `await` statement and goes to sleep. You then copy `undefined` from `test4` to `test5`. Later the promise returned from `test3` resolves and the IIFE wakes up and assigns a new value to `test4`. It's too late for `test5` which you've already copied `undefined` to. The duplicate is still a duplicate. You're just trying all sorts of things that it doesn't say you can or should do.